# Infinite CABasicAnimation stops

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, cabasicanimation

I 've an infinite animation (rotating an image, type: `CABasicAnimation`) in my UIView with

```
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
```

When I push a new ViewController and go back to the initial ViewController with the animation containing View inside, the rotation stopped.

Even if I set up the animation again when the ViewController's `viewWillAppear` method gets called, it won't rotate again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see how Xcode has anything to do with this.

Comment: You're right. I removed the xcode tag.

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to use the "ios" and "cocoa-touch" tags for general iOS programming questions.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Actually, there is a simple way to solve this
setting your animation to this:

*Swift 3 version*

```
animation.removedOnCompletion = false
```

*Swift 4 version*

```
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

The layer itself isn't destroyed, when NavigationController is being pushed to another ViewController's view, because UINavigationController got `viewControllers` property which will retain the original viewController and therefore its view and your animated layer.

**It is this CABasicAnimation object destroyed** when view removed from interface even though you set its repeatCount to infinite. So set the `isRemovedOnCompletion` to false to keep it.

Comment: True. My animation worked fine on iOS8 but iOS9 requires this setting.

Comment: I have kind of a similar problem. My view that is pulsing is inside of a `UICollectionView` and when I reload my collectionView, the animations stop. Any idea on where to start searching for that?

Comment: Hmm, this is a great tip, but indeed it does not help in the UITableView case  :/

Comment: Another tip: Setting `isRemovedOnCompletion` to false did not solved the issue for me. In my case I did not push a new VC into the navigation stack, but presented another VC modally. I wrote a custom CALayer subclass that did handle the animation (using code generated by PaintCode). Overriding `removeAllAnimations` in the CALayer subclass + setting the animations `isRemovedOnCompletion` property to false did solve the issue finally.

Answer (score 5):

When a layer is removed from the screen, it loses its animations.  You need to add them back once the layer is on the screen again.

`viewWillAppear:` is too early, because the layer isn't actually on the screen by that time.  Try adding the animation in `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: I thought I've already tried `viewDidAppear`, but it seems i haven't. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I did try in viewDidAppear after the app went in background mode and back, it's not even called!

Comment: Try observing the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification and re-adding your animations there.